# It's possible to change preview size in thunar?

Tags: thunar, previews

I like thunar but I would like to change its maximum and unsettable preview size.

By default use a dimension of about 64x64 and I would prefer to use a size of 128x128.
I think it's possible to do it in some way, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1596 has a discussion on this. I think the answer is "not yet".

Answer (score 0):

When you open thunar, go to the view menu and click zoom in until you get the right icon size. You can also use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom in.

I think there may be a way to set the default value in Xfconf, but I have not been able to confirm this.

Comment: The maximum size you can set in thunar is 64x64. I think in the manual config files you can overcome this limit. I'll search in the xfconf. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can try `pcmanfm`:

[image: pcmanfm thumbnail display preferences]